# Monotouch: Table not displaying elements when source is set

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to add a UITableView in IB, then later set the Source. When I set the source, the table is not filled with the elements that I add. When I scroll the table, then the elements are visible in the bottom.

If I do the exact same thing in code, that is Create a new table, set the source, then add the table to the view, then everything looks as expected.

Could anyone enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong or not doing. I have tried to call reloadData after the source is set, but no result.

Thanks in advance 
Søren Rokkedal

Comment: Where are you setting the source?

Comment: My guess is that when you set it up in IB, your table view is not filling the window, and is instead at the bottom, so that you have to scroll to see it.  It's hard to say for sure without seeing what you're doing.  Can you paste a screenshot of your layout from IB?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have some **static cells** in your table view.

Go to the IB and change the UITableView's content mode.

[image]